# changed .htaccess and now website has gone blank and can't change it back

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Trying to do SEO on my website. Wanted to make sure that http:// goes to www. to improve google results. Changed .htaccess as proposed on a website and now I get the 404 message when I am trying to safe the old file back. Website doesnt show anything but a blank white screen (no error).
original .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What I put:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.URL\.ch [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.URL.ch/$1 [L,R=301]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Anyone has an idea how I can save the old code so the website works again?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert rewrite rule after `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.URL\.ch [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.URL.ch/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also remember to change site and home URL in WP permalinks also.

Comment: Thanks. But my main problem now is, that I cannot save anything. Probably because I should have changed permalinks before?

Comment: And my website seems to reload itself permanently - did I produce a loop?

Comment: Error Message for trying to save is: Not found - the requested URL /wp-admin/admin.php was not found on this server. Apache Server at (my URL) Port 80)

Comment: Comment out new rule and try again in new browser.

Comment: I cannot get to the Wordpress Dashboard at the moment. Tried in new browser window. Same error. thanks anyway! Appreciate!

Comment: You can directly change these values from PHPMyAdmin or a MySQL client.

Comment: OK, that's newland to me. I have to get a password for this from my host... Thank you so much!